# Avoiding negation for three booleans (PMD rule)

Tags: java, pmd

I have a situation with the following (simplified) code:

```
if (x== null && y == null && z == null) {
   logger.warning("bla bla");
} else if (x != null) {
   // Do some dispatch for x
} else if (y != null) {
   // Do some dispatch for y
} else {
   // Do some dispatch for z
}
```

I'm getting a PMD violation for the  `* != null` expressions (even though I delibirately started with a positive comparison (`==`) for the if case.

> Confusing ternary (pmd:ConfusingTernary)
>
> In an if expression with an else clause, avoid negation in the test.
>
> For example, rephrase: if (x != y) diff(); else same(); as: if (x == y) same(); else diff(); Most if (x != y) cases without an else are often return cases, so consistent use of this rule makes the code easier to read.
>
> Also, this resolves trivial ordering problems, such as does the error case go first? or does the common case go first?.

**How should I rewrite these expressions?**

Answer (score 0):

How about this :

```
if (x != null) {
    // Do some dispatch for x
} else if (y != null) {
    // Do some dispatch for y
} else if (z != null) {
   // Do some dispatch for z
} else {
   log.warn("error msg");
}
```

Comment: SonarLint (IntelliJ plugin for SonarQube) seems to accept it which I think is odd as the rule definition says:

"In an if expression with an else clause, avoid negation in the test."

Comment: SonarLint will not use rules from PMD. It uses only SonarJava plugin